# When the device is x-small, make the divs in the same line (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see my code and jsfiddle below.

I want that when I minimize the browser to Extra-Small Deviece it will show the left side in one line (without the title "TITLE 1") in the center. Something like that: http://oi67.tinypic.com/10hksxs.jpg

Code:

```
<div class="container text-center">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
     <h4><strong>TITLE 1</strong></h4>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">
      <p class="mid-image-block"><strong>MINI TITLE</strong>
      <br>TEXT
      <br>TEXT2 </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">
      <p class="mid-image-block"><strong>MINI TITLE</strong>
      <br>TEXT
      <br>TEXT2 </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">
      <p class="mid-image-block"><strong>MINI TITLE</strong>
      <br>TEXT
      <br>TEXT2 </p>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
  <h4><strong>TITLE 2
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/864/

Thanks!

Comment: just add class "col-xs-12" do any element that you want to take up an entire line for extra smal devices .  You should keep in mind though that bootstrap defines extra small as 480px, you might need to customize bootstrap if you want a different view for vertically holding phone from horizontal

Comment: I tried it.... don't work...

Comment: Why do you want to have everything on one line in extra small mode? This does not make any sense. The goal of bootstrap xs mode is to have everything in one column (not in one row/line), that you can scroll vertically instead of horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's what you looking for: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/Wy22s/865/)

```
<div class="container text-center">
 <div class="row hidden-xs">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
     <h4><strong>TITLE 1</strong></h4>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
     <h4><strong>TITLE 2</strong></h4>
   </div>
 </div> 

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 text-left">
        <p class="mid-image-block"><strong>MINI TITLE</strong>
         <br>TEXT
         <br>TEXT2 </p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>


  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 text-left">
        <p class="mid-image-block"><strong>MINI TITLE</strong>
         <br>TEXT
         <br>TEXT2 </p>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png">
      </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 text-left">
    <p class="mid-image-block"><strong>MINI TITLE</strong>
      <br>TEXT
      <br>TEXT2 </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```